# Google play/ Game Centre access friends stats on games

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Hi i would like to know if its possible to access via API on google play or Game Centre your friends list to see they're stats and achievements on a game you play together.
I would like to build a app that compares (like challenges) progress on a game played by two friends.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to `Google` it before?

Comment: yes  i have found ways to get the stats from my own game as garardnimo also points out.what i am trying to ask is if i can get a 3rd party game stats a game that 2 of my app users are both playing (lets say Clash of clans) so my app can compare they're progress.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [Play Services for Android](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart), especially [social leaderboards](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#public_and_social_leaderboards), which is made up of people in the user's circle. You may also want to check out [Adding Player Stats to Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/stats) which contains the player's in-game activity, but I think this deals with all players in a game instead of just the friend list.

Comment: yes the difference is that i would like to get some 3rd party game stats into my app and compare them lets say how much gold player A and B have on a game.

Comment: any thoughts on that ? still no luck!